# Crear tablas a partir de consultas mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

Cómo se podría crear una tabla a partir de varias consultas en `mysql`. tengo las siguientes consultas:

```
--selecciona tipo gasto sin repetir un registro --- 
SELECT DISTINCT tipo_gasto FROM factura`
```

cantidad de registros de esa variable

`SELECT COUNT(tipo_gasto) cantidad FROM factura WHERE tipo_gasto = 'vivienda'`

Suma las columnas tipo_gasto

`SELECT ROUND(SUM(valor_base),2) total FROM factura WHERE tipo_gasto = 'VIV'`

Es posible elaborar una tabla a partir de estas consultas?

Comment: bienvenido a la comunidad.!!
un consejo si quieres hacer una pregunta pon siquiera un par de codigos como lo estas haciendo, o que malo te esta ocurriendo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Todo es posible... o casi todo. También es posible obtener todos los datos necesarios a través de **una sola consulta** y crear la tabla a partir de ese resultado. Si las diferentes tablas que intervienen en la (s) consulta (s) están relacionadas (imagino que sí, puesto que quieres construir una tabla de resultados a partir de ellas), la mejor manera sería construir una consulta SQL que te traiga todos los datos haciendo una sola llamada a la base de datos, uniendo las tablas mediante `JOIN` en sus claves primarias/foráneas.

Comment: una consulta estaría bien pues los datos proviene de una sola tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ese caso solo le falta agrupar por tipo_gasto. Proba de esta forma:

```
SELECT tipo_gasto, count(tipo_gasto), ROUND(SUM(valor_base),2) 
    FROM factura GROUP BY tipo_gasto
```

Comment: Gracias hermano! pues probé con `order by` pero no recorde con `group by`

Answer (score 0):

En efecto puedes crear tablas temporales de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nombreTablaTemporal aqui_tu_consulta;
```

Estas tablas temporales se pueden guardar

Si tienes alguna duda comenta.

Suerte.

**Actualizacion**

Un aproximacion a tu problema seria:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporal SELECT tipo_gasto, count(tipo_gasto), ROUND(SUM(valor_base),2) FROM factura WHERE tipo_gasto = 'VIV' AND tipo_gasto = 'vivienda';

SELECT * FROM temporal;
```

Y este seria para consultar por todos los tipos de gastos:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporal SELECT tipo_gasto, count(tipo_gasto), ROUND(SUM(valor_base),2) FROM factura GROUP BY tipo_gasto;

SELECT * FROM temporal;
```

Comment: Gracias hermano! pues la consulta corre perfecta solo q en mysql omitimos as y () , podria ademas imprimir varios resgistros de tipo_gasto omitiendo where?

Comment: Si, solo necesitarias quitar el la sentencia WHERE, solo como recordatorio, si la respuesta te parece correcta no olvides marcarla como tal ;)

Comment: no mi hermano solo con retirando esa sentencia no me devuelve la lista deseada como esta:

Comment: |viv  |  2 | 145                                                                                                      |edu| 1  | 210 que serian 2 filas distintas solo me devuelve una

Comment: Estas usando distinct?, actualice la respuesta ve si te funciona

Comment: lo utilice y lo quite pero el resultado es solo |viv |3 (de la suma de los registros) |365 de la suma de los totales  'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporal SELECT tipo_gasto, count(tipo_gasto), ROUND(SUM(valor_base),2) FROM factura;
SELECT * FROM temporal;'

Comment: Creo saber cual es la razon, no podrias darme un modelo de la relacion entre estas tablas. La razon por la que solo sale un resultado es por la estructura del query, primero debemos obtener los tipos de pagos y eso unirlo con el resultado de las operaciones con cada tipo de pago, para que no se unan en un solo valor.

Answer (score 0):

EN SQL PUEDES USAR LA INSTRUCCIÓN CREATE TABLE.

**SINTAXIS:**

```
CREATE TABLE < NOMBRE DE LA TABLA > (

    // COLUMNAS Y SU TIPO DE DATO
    < NOMBRE DE LA COLUMNA > < TIPO DE DATO >

    // LLAVE PRIMARIA
    PRIMARY KEY(< NOMBRE DE LA COLUMNA >)

);
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta. El OP no busca conocer como crear tablas si no como crear una tabla a partir de una serie de consultas.